# Descriptive statistics interpretation of log-transformed variables

Tags: interpretation, descriptive-statistics, moments, logarithm

How can I interpret the descriptive statistics of logarithmic transform variables

- mean
- maximum
- minimum
- standard deviation
- kurtosis
- Skewness
  ?

  In case I use log transformed form of the variables in my analysis,  do I have the right to use the descriptive statistics of the non transformed variables?

Comment: It would be perfectly valid to report e.g. the skewness of the original variables and the skewness of the transformed variables. That's part of the evidence on the effects of the transformation.